# Class Limits, boundaries, midpoint, relative frequency?

Tags: statistics

I have a list:

85
45
75
60
90
90
115
30
55
58
78
120
80
65
65
140
65
50
30
125
75
137
80
120
15
45
70
65
50
45
95
70
70
28
40
125
105
75
80
70
90
68
73
75
55
70
95
65
200
75
15
90
46
33
100
65
60
55
85
50
10
68
99
145
45
75
45
95
85
65
65
52
82

Sorry for the poor formatting, but I created a program that would count the frequencies, etc. and I still am getting the problem wrong.

The class limits make sense to me since the smallest value is 10 and you just need to add 28 (the class width), and the next should be 48, right? Or am I completely off base?

Class boundaries will make sense once I get the right values for the class limits.

The midpoint should be the lower limit + the upper, so wouldn't the midpoint of (10 + 38)/2 be 24??

And relative frequency is just the frequency divided by the total frequencies, right?

[image]

Thanks for your help :/

Comment: If one class goes from $10$ to $38$, then the next class should start from $39$. Otherwise, if you get a data point of, say, $42$, what class would you put it in?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the tally of your numbers:

```
{{65, 8}, {75, 6}, {45, 5}, {70, 5}, {90, 4}, {50, 3}, {55, 3}, {80, 
  3}, {85, 3}, {95, 3}, {15, 2}, {30, 2}, {60, 2}, {68, 2}, {120, 
  2}, {125, 2}, {10, 1}, {28, 1}, {33, 1}, {40, 1}, {46, 1}, {52, 
  1}, {58, 1}, {73, 1}, {78, 1}, {82, 1}, {99, 1}, {100, 1}, {105, 
  1}, {115, 1}, {137, 1}, {140, 1}, {145, 1}, {200, 1}}
```

And here's the histogram with bin width = 1, thus replicating the above tally:

[image]

The mean is 73.7, the quartiles are {54.3, 70, 90}.  There's many more summary statistics that can computed.

What method are you using to classify (ie, partition the x-axis) or cluster the data?

Comment: I did the calculations on [*Statiscope*](http://www.df.lth.se/~mikaelb/statiscope/statiscope.html) and they match your. Regards

Comment: These stats are great, thanks so much! So if I made a frequency table, would the limits be 10-38, 48-76, etc? Or is that wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by limits. I take it you want to cluster the data into classes but based on what method? Different methods give different "limits". Where did the numbers: 10-38, 48-76, etc come from?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not exactly sure what method the problem suggested. I made a frequency table and am supposed to find the class limits when I divide the problem into seven classes (from the image I linked to). So with 7 classes, (200-10/2) = 28 (the class width), but how would I find the class limits for each class?

Comment: You can certainly do that: partition the range [10,200] into 7 (or any number) of equal segments. In that case no other information about the data is needed, only the Min=10 and Max=200. But it is more informative to partition the range into quantiles (check wikipedia). For example, if you split into quartiles, you get the partition [10,54.7],[54.7,70],[70,90],[90,120]. Each quartile contains approximately 1/4 of the data points. 70 here is the median value, and [54.7,90] is called the interquartile range. These are commonly used summary stats.